# How I can manually award bounty to non-own answer? I don't see this link

Tags: support, bounty, grace-period

I started bounty to not my question 7 days ago and the question still *has not answers*. Now I have a grace period for this bounty.

My question: **How I can award this bounty to answer on other question?** On any question page I see "`start a bounty`" (bounty for the question) but **I don't see any link to award bounty to answers...**

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

View the bounty on your question like you would a payment for an ad in the newspaper - you pay for the increased attention, but success is not guaranteed.